# Was Darth Sidious's "Force Scream" the reason the other masters died so quickly?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, revenge-of-the-sith

So the title says it all really, was the only reason Darth Sidious killed the other masters so quickly down to the fact he used a "Force Scream" did it disrupt or disorientate the other masters apart from Windu?
The description of a force scream is:

> If a Dark Jedi or Sith Lord was being beaten and frustrated by his foe, he might let out an enraged scream (amplified through the Force) that triggered shock waves that rippled through the Force. This caused devastation to any that were unfortunate enough to be in proximity. Like many dark side Force powers, it allowed the user to use powerful negative emotions as a weapon, albeit involuntarily in this case.
>
> The Force scream had been called "a wave of hatred, amplified and fueled by the dark side, that is capable of smashing through mental and physical defenses with ease." A number of references to Dark Jedi in Old Republic archives often mentioned the Dark Jedi violently losing control in the final moments of battle.
>
> <sub><sup>[Wookieepedia: Force Scream (Legends)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_scream)</sup></sub>

Could this mean that it disrupted the other Jedi Masters except Mace?

Comment: Where are you getting that description from?

Comment: @Thunderforge - It's from the (Legends) description of a Force Scream on Wookieepedia

Comment: From the movie, it looks like a perfect surprise attack. I do not remember any mention of special force uses by Sidious at this scene in the novellization